# Excel 2010: Trying to paste hexadecimal into cells and stopping excel's auto formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Anyone with some Excel expertise please help me with this...

I'm trying to copy and paste 4 digit hexadecimal numbers (eg. 0001, 0002, all the way through to 03D2) but Excel keeps formatting them, 0001 becomes 1, while some hex become '####' which is strange. How would I stop this autoformatting? Note I only want to turn it off just for this time. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Format all the necessary cells as "Text" in the worksheet you're going to paste to. And then use Paste special->values

That should do the trick

Answer (score 3):

Before you paste the data set the column to be text in the formatting options and make sure you are pasting simple text eg Use Paste special and text.

If you need to do Maths on the numbers use HEX2DEC() to convert the field to decimal and to go back to Hex use DEC2HEX()

Comment: I'll keep this in mind when I need to convert, thanks :D